# XNA Additive particles blending on background

Tags: background, xna, blending

I got a problem with my particle engine that i'm trying to implement in a game i'm currently coding. It looks fine on a black background but I forgot the particles would blend with the background if I added one.
Is there any way I can prevent my particles from blending with the background and only let them blend with eachother?

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone, null);
Main.TileMap.Draw(spriteBatch);
spriteBatch.End();

spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.Additive, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone, null);
Main.ParticleManager.Draw(spriteBatch);
spriteBatch.End();
```

Here's some images to show you what I mean:

http://puu.sh/1O6Zf

http://puu.sh/1O6Yl

Edit: I solved it by rendering it to a texture and draw it to the screen.
Here's the fixed code:

```
    RenderTarget2D renderTarget;
    Texture2D particleMap;
public void LoadContent(ContentManager content)
{
    renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(Main.graphicsDevice, pp.BackBufferWidth, pp.BackBufferHeight, true, Main.graphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Format, DepthFormat.Depth24);
}
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        Main.graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);
        Main.graphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.Additive, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone, null);
        Main.ParticleManager.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();

        Main.graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
        particleMap = (Texture2D)renderTarget;

        Main.graphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        Main.TileMap.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.Draw(particleMap, new Vector2(0, 0), null, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(0, 0), 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1);

        spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help you. To make texture half transparent:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, location, Color.White * 0.5f);
```

so changing value from `0.0f` to `1.0f` will give you transparency strength.

also make sure you to sent blend state

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend)
```